# Error while trying to install python in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

The error while trying this cmd is

```
python-software-properties : Depends: python-pycurl but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
>> sudo apt-get update
>> sudo apt-get update --fix-missing && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

then:

```
>> apt-get install -y python-dev
```

Comment: * Remember that python is by default at your system